# How to migrate password hashes from Passlib.bcrypt to Django's default pbkdf2_sha256?

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt, pbkdf2

I had a FastAPI app that had been using Passlib's bcrypt module to hash passwords.
Here's an example string that is stored in the database as a password: `$2b$12$62GCnIkiQp7dE/N2.Al4t.ODW.JYXCz8rHHmaLt63NnML4xDgKhFK`

Now, the problem is I'm not sure whether it's possible to migrate this hash over to my new django application, since django stores hashes in a string that looks like this: `<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`

I thought the solution could be that the PassLib hash is B64 encoded, but I'm not really sure how to decode it into something that works for Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after trying around I came up with the solution

First: add `"django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher"` to `settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS`

Now, you can to every string that looks `$2b$12$62GCnIkiQp7dE/N2.Al4t.ODW.JYXCz8rHHmaLt63NnML4xDgKhFK` you add `bcrypt$` for the result to look like `bcrypt$$2b$12$62GCnIkiQp7dE/N2.Al4t.ODW.JYXCz8rHHmaLt63NnML4xDgKhFK`.
Not sure why there have to be two dollar signs after the method name, but if they are not there - django raises an exception: it expect 5 objects from `hash.split("$")`, and the second object is called "empty".

After doing this to my passwords that I used in my FastAPI app and adding users to django, authorization started to work.